# Hibernate 5 gives error: must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-5.x

I have been migrating from hibernate 4 to hibernate 5. It is ok in hibernate 4, but doesn't work in hibernate 5.

I am getting exception:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key
>   (FKf6eo63yo42ylh7vl5klap2eum:ProductParent [parent_id])) must have
>   same number of columns as the referenced primary key (ProductParent
>   [parent_id,product_id])

This is my hibernate mapping:

@Entity
public class ProductParent implements Serializable {

```
@Id
@OneToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
private AbstractProduct product = new AbstractProduct();

@ManyToMany(cascade = ALL, fetch = EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = PRODUCTPARENT, joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "product_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id") })
private Set<ProductParent> parents = new HashSet<>();
```

and table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE productparent (  
  product_id bigint NOT NULL,  
  parent_id bigint,  
  CONSTRAINT fk_parent_id FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES abstractproduct (id) MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,  
  CONSTRAINT fk_product_id FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES abstractproduct (id) MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,  
  CONSTRAINT product_id_parent_id_should_be_unique UNIQUE (product_id, parent_id)  
)
```

Could you help me that?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

To add:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = PARENT_ID)
private AbstractProduct parent = new AbstractProduct();
```